# Ubuntu: Move fsbackup backups to Amazon S3

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I have a legacy server (Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic x86), where previous admin set up backups with fsbackup.

This server lives in a VPS (under some kind of Xen), and it is low on HDD space (16 GB total).

Now it came to a point, where fsbackup backups take more space than the rest of data in the system. The filesystem is 100% filled, and I already cleaned up all that I could, aside from actual backups.

I do not have any experience managing fsbackup, and I do not want to break or lose the backups. Googling fsbackup gives surprisingly low quality results...

Here is how my backups look like:

```
$ sudo ls -lh /var/archives
total 8.1G
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  318 2011-01-06 06:26 myserver-20110106.md5
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  258 2011-01-07 06:26 myserver-20110107.md5
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  318 2011-01-08 06:26 myserver-20110108.md5
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  318 2011-01-09 06:26 myserver-20110109.md5
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  346 2011-01-10 06:43 myserver-20110110.md5
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  14M 2011-01-06 06:26 myserver-all-mysql-databases.20110106.sql.bz2
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  14M 2011-01-07 06:26 myserver-all-mysql-databases.20110107.sql.bz2
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  14M 2011-01-08 06:26 myserver-all-mysql-databases.20110108.sql.bz2
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  14M 2011-01-09 06:26 myserver-all-mysql-databases.20110109.sql.bz2
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  862 2011-01-10 06:43 myserver-all-mysql-databases.20110110.sql.bz2
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 827K 2011-01-03 06:25 myserver-etc.20110103.master.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  16K 2011-01-06 06:25 myserver-etc.20110106.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  16K 2011-01-07 06:25 myserver-etc.20110107.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  16K 2011-01-08 06:25 myserver-etc.20110108.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  16K 2011-01-09 06:25 myserver-etc.20110109.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 827K 2011-01-10 06:25 myserver-etc.20110110.master.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root  36K 2011-01-10 06:25 myserver-etc.incremental.bin
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  29M 2011-01-03 06:25 myserver-home.20110103.master.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  11K 2011-01-06 06:25 myserver-home.20110106.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  14K 2011-01-07 06:25 myserver-home.20110107.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  11K 2011-01-08 06:25 myserver-home.20110108.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  11K 2011-01-09 06:25 myserver-home.20110109.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 2.0M 2011-01-10 06:25 myserver-home.20110110.master.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root  27K 2011-01-10 06:25 myserver-home.incremental.bin
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5G 2011-01-03 06:29 myserver-opt.20110103.master.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5M 2011-01-06 06:25 myserver-opt.20110106.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5M 2011-01-07 06:25 myserver-opt.20110107.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5M 2011-01-08 06:25 myserver-opt.20110108.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5M 2011-01-09 06:25 myserver-opt.20110109.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1.5G 2011-01-10 06:30 myserver-opt.20110110.master.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 201K 2011-01-10 06:30 myserver-opt.incremental.bin
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 2.3G 2011-01-03 06:41 myserver-srv.20110103.master.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  44M 2011-01-06 06:26 myserver-srv.20110106.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  27M 2011-01-07 06:25 myserver-srv.20110107.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  39M 2011-01-08 06:26 myserver-srv.20110108.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 2.0M 2011-01-09 06:25 myserver-srv.20110109.tar.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 2.7G 2011-01-10 06:42 myserver-srv.20110110.master.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 3.4M 2011-01-10 06:42 myserver-srv.incremental.bin
```

I'm thinking about moving backups to Amazon S3, but before that I have to free some space, so the server can work.

Perhaps I can mount /var/archives to an Amazon S3 bucket somehow...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use the Fuse (filesystems-in-user-space) feature of the Linux kernel to mount an S3 bucket as if it were a normal local filesystem. There's several implementations of this; [here is one that I know is being actively developed](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon).

There are some potential downsides to be aware of, like the fact that you pay for doing simple things like file listings. Not much, but if an automated process does it a lot, you could be in for a surprise. (So you probably don't want to leave the filesystem mounted and accessible to anything except when you're intentionally using it.)

So, without weighing in on the wisdom of the approach in general, there's one way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Moving those files shouldn't be an issue. This [article](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) is what I used. Its a little sparse on details but it will basically let you mount Amazon S3 to migrate those files. Best of luck!

Comment: I can't install s3fs on Ubuntu 9.10 — it requires fuse 2.8.4 which appears only in Natty.

Comment: Well, I installed fuse 2.8.4 from deb files, but can't say I like it...

Comment: And now s3fs turned zombie on me. No good... :-(

Comment: Looks like that s3fs can't work if there is not enough space on local drive... Too bad.